# What "Add as library" does in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm creating an application with a plugin system in Java. I can import my plugins only if i've right-clicked on the .jar before and clicked on "Add as library". Otherwise, i got an error.

My question is : What Intellij does when I click on this button ? Also, what can I do to generate my .jar like a library without clicking on this button ?

Here is a picture for better understanding :
[image: Capture Screen of the option]

Answer (score 0):

Add as Library, as the name implies, it actually allows you to (include a .jar or a file containing a .jar) to your project or module.

To generate a .jar archive from a project/module/class you can execute a maven command e.g. mvn clean package.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a jar file and adds it as a library in your project (dependency on your classpath in execution and inside your lib folder in your packaging)

Comment: Then it ask you to put this jar as a dependency to another project or as a global library.

Comment: My problem is that this jar is a plugin and i want to add it dynamicaly to class path.

Comment: Build it, go to the project you wish to add it 

Click File from File menu then Project Structure, select Modules at the left panel, dependencies tab Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar